# Haskell - Unification problem while wrapping my function with another one

Tags: haskell

```
frequency xs = toList (fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- xs])

freqBigrams [x]=[]
freqBigrams[]=[]
freqBigrams (x:y:xs) = frequency(  [ ( x,y) ] ++freqBigrams (y:xs) )
```

Type error in function binding
*** Term           : freqBigrams**
 Type           : [a] -> [((a,a),a)]
 **Does not match : [a] -> [(a,a)]
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type

i don't know what is the problem with the unification or how i can fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not calculate the frequencies on the result of the `freqBigrams`. The `freqBigrams` will calculate the frequencies of the bigrams, and then you pepend that with a bigram itself.

What might be better here is to define two functions, each with a clear purpose. For example you can define a function `bigrams`:

```
bigrams :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
bigrams (x:xs@(y:_)) = (x, y) : bigrams xs
bigrams [_] = []
bigrams [] = []
```

Next you calculate the `freqBigrams` by using `frequency` on `bigrams`:

```
freqBigrams :: (Ord k, Num a) => [k] -> [((k, k), a)]
freqBigrams = frequency . bigrams
```

For example we can calculate the frequency of a list of characters with:

```
Prelude Data.Map> freqBigrams "abcacacb"
[(('a','b'),1),(('a','c'),2),(('b','c'),1),(('c','a'),2),(('c','b'),1)]
```

By performing this in one function a problem will occur with the recursion. Indeed:

```
freqBigrams (x:y:xs) = frequency(  [ ( x,y) ] ++ freqBigrams (y:xs) )
                                   \___ ____/    \______ _________/
                                       v                v
                                    [(a,a)]         [(?, Int)]
```

Here the `[(x,y)]` is thus a list that contains one bigram, whereas the `freqBigrams` will somehow calculate the frequencies of the tail, this will thus have a type that looks like `[(?,Int)]`. This will thus only work if `a ~ ? ~ Int`, in which case `freqBigrams :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]`, but then it still does not match, since if that holds, then `frequency` will convert this `[(Int, Int)]` to a `[((Int, Int), Int)]`, and thus we get a type mismatch.

Comment: it gives me an error when i use the freqBigrams method Syntax error in input (unexpected `::')

Comment: @MidoAshraf: I have tested this with a list of characters, as you can see, it calculates that `ac` and `ca` occur twice, and `ab`, `bc` and `cb` once.